# How to subscribe to the property change of an object referenced within another object in rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, rxjs6

I am really new to both Angular and RxJS. I am trying to create an Angular component which allows different objects to share a tree-structured data set.

Here's my scenario in an imaginary and simplified way - an Angular component to post an entire company structure to the server. This structure is a composite of multiple "StuffDto" object, which references each other as their manager. And all stuffs share a same company department structure map.

The multi-level structure map is like:

- Marketing Dept

  - Sales Dept

    - In-store Sales Team
    - On-site Sales Team
  - Advertisement Dept

    - Planner Team
    - Designer Team
- Manufacturing Dept

  - R&D Dept

    - Engineer Team
    - Researcher Team
  - QA Dept

    - Inspector Team
    - Assurance Team

Here's my `StaffDto` class which will be posted to the server directly upon submission.

```
export class StaffDto {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    assignedDept?: string;
    managerId?: string;
}
```

Here's my `Stuff` object which will be passed around my Angular applications.

```
export class Stuff {
    data: StuffDto;
    _manager: Stuff;

    get manager(): Stuff {
        return this._manager;
    }

    set manager(manager: Stuff) {
        this._manager = manager;
        this.data.managerId = manager.data.id;
    }
}
```

This will work in some straightforward scenarios, But not all of them.

If I create Peter and Tom, then set Peter to be Tom's manager. Here's what the 2 `StuffDto` objects look like.

```
{ id: abc01,
  name: 'Peter',
  assignedDept: 'Marketing Dept',
  managerId: null }
{ id: abc02,
  name: 'Tom',
  assignedDept: 'Sales Dept',
  managerId: 'abc01' }
```

If I change Peter's `id` from "abc01" to "abc01a", I would expect tom's `ManagerId` to be changed as well. Also if I change Peter's `assignedDept` form "Marketing Dept" to "R&D Dept", since there will not be "Sales Dept" underneath Peter's department for Tom to be assigned, Tom's `assignedDept` should be cleared to null.

I am not quite sure this could be done by subscription of RxJS. I've tried to make `_manager` a `Subject` and then subscribe to it. But the function will only be called whenever a new manager is assigned, not with the manager's property change.

I am wondering whether there's a way to do it without changing too much of the code. As the `StuffDto` will be passed to the server I won't be able to change that.

Comment: this is more like a record set iteration and update question other rxjs. You don't need to use rxjs for this.

Comment: @FanCheung Could you be more specific?

Comment: You can just put the iteration and update logic in your setter to update the staff list, rxjs is to handle mostly async operations. If you just getting started with RXJS i won't recommand you do array processing with it.

Comment: Look at a state management library like NGRX or NGXS - they are the right way to manage complex shared app-wide state, all of this logic would then have a neat and clean place to live. You certainly /could/ hack something together yourself from plain observables to solve this, but given the sorts of changes you are talking about, it would be complex, very specific, and very hard to test cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, [this](https://blog.angularindepth.com/rxjs-how-to-observe-an-object-20c47cf51571) @cartant's article could be what you are looking for.

The idea is to wrap your objects in a way that every property has its own observable and to use a proxy object for assignments.

I hope this fits your needs.

Comment: That link is dead. Can you post the code/answer here please